# Safe to mutate in `pre_dispatch`/`validate`?

Tags: polkadot, pallet, parachain, runtime

Is it safe to do a mutation from within a SignedExtension for some pallet-specific storage items while validating a transaction? If not, what could go wrong, and why?

One thing that could go wrong is if `pre_dispatch` / `validate` are called separately, it could trigger the mutation multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is safe to mutate storage items from `pre_dispatch`. Mutating storage items from `validate` doesn't make that much sense as it is only called in an offchain context. However, as the docs say you should ensure that `pre_dispatch` and `validate` are doing the exact same validity checks as otherwise your chain is attackable.
Whatever you are doing, you just need to take into account that the dispatchable is maybe "failing" and didn't do what you expected in your `pre_dispatch`. So, you may need to use `post_dispatch` to do some corrections.